# Core Data fetchedResultsController errors 'A fetch request must have an entity' entityForName returns nil

Tags: xcode, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hi I set up my own coredata app, or I tried...
First I created the xdatamodel and generated the Modelclasses, after this I implemented all the function of core-data in AppDelegate which I found in a generated project.  Finally I copied the fetchedResultsController in my TableViewController.
fetchedResultsController

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (fetchedResultsController_ != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController_;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ParameterGroup" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

[aFetchedResultsController release];
[fetchRequest release];
[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![fetchedResultsController_ performFetch:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return fetchedResultsController_;
}
```

First I checked if the managedObjectsController is != nil, it has a address
Then I copied the EntityName from my xdatamodel in entityForName,
but NSEntityDescricption entity is nil.

And if I just create a new object the exception says, that the entity doesn't exist

Do I have to connect the xdatamodel to my project?
Hope you can help me
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this, given that you haven't done a lot coding on non-core-data parts, is probably to create a new project where you check the box for "Use Core Data". If you're going to use a Navigation Bar, choose this as your template. If I recall correctly, this will generate a table view with all functions needed. You'll have to modify the datamodel (generated).

Remark that you'll have to delete the app from the Simulator if it is installed and you change the datamodel (otherwise the generated data will not be consistent with the datamodel and the app will crash)

Comment: Scorched earth debugging. Sometimes, you just gotta do it.

Answer (score 3):

The most common cause of this problem is simply misspelling the entity name wrong in the code such that it doesn't match the entity name in the data model.

Copy and paste the entity name from the model to the code and see if that fixes the problem.